# problem when adding jquery.js file

Tags: 7, javascript

I need to run jquery code in my content type form so i added jquery-1.8.0.min.js file in info file of my theme.

after clear all caches something wrong happened, the "add more" button on date field stop working, i'm sure it's from adding the js file.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Do you want to add your own inline jQuery code (and not jQuery itself) inside the *edit node* page?

Comment: yes i want to run my code in node edit form, but it's not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal already includes jQuery. You should not add another jQuery library because this can cause conflicts with the existing one.

I suggest you to use [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) if you want to use another version of jQuery.

If what you want is to run your own javascript code, you could add it using [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

Hint: Try first with `alert('hello world')`. See [Working with JavaScript and jQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213).

Comment: my jquery code does not execute inside drupal code

Comment: i'm so sory drupal core (drupal website)

Comment: Ok, see updated answer. And please read the documentation :)